# Angularjs + Google oauth2 + get id_token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I am try to implement google auth in angualjs.
But I researched and get code in javascript.

Code:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="148699057185-ug1ge86g4dn4uffffekth3rb7382cl2333323238fau.apps.googleusercontent.com">
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
        <script>

            function onSignIn(googleUser) {
                // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
                var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                console.log("ID: " + profile.getId());
                // Don't send this directly to your server!
                console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
                console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
                console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
                // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);

                alert(id_token);

                // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting alert the id_token.

But i need to convert into angularjs.

I tried to implement to angularjs but its not working.

Please anyone help me.

Expect: I need to get only id_token(not access token) from google oauth in angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [angular-google-plus](https://github.com/mrzmyr/angular-google-plus) module. It is a complete angular module which handles the login with the Google+ API.

Here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/jvHVtNedJoPcqRKg8OLz?p=preview) (Don't forget to insert your client ID in the code.)

**Example usage:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['googleplus']);

app.config(['GooglePlusProvider', function(GooglePlusProvider) {
     GooglePlusProvider.init({
        clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
     });
}]);

app.controller('AuthCtrl', ['$scope', 'GooglePlus', function ($scope, GooglePlus) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        GooglePlus.login().then(function (authResult) {
            console.log(authResult);

            GooglePlus.getUser().then(function (user) {
                console.log(user);
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
}]);
```

I think `authResult` object should contain what you want.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I expect the authResult including id_token. but now its not getting id_token